# Create column that tracks the cumulative number of instances in a different column

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following data. I'm trying to create the Primary Key which uses logic from the Month, Name, and the number of cumulative times the MonthName have occurred at that point in the data. Is there a way to do this in SQL?

[image]

Comment: yes. but what have you tried and what RDBMS is this?

Comment: and why do you want to create so exotic primary key ?

Comment: That's **not** a good candidate PK, a PK must be unique and as compact as possible, Names. counts and months are not unique. what's wrong with an identity/autonumber?

Comment: Please update the question tag with your RDBMS (sql server, mysql, postgres, oracle, etc).  Ultimately what you are looking for is a window function to calculate the cumsum of the count of records. The "primary key" column would just be basic concatenation. If you share your RDBMS we can help further.

Comment: Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/yI5mJLE1 using a row_number  but just because you can should you?  why not just make a composite key based on month and name and date or some other field which makes the record unique.  Smart keys generally aren't smart... or use an autonumber/identify as a surrogate key... Put another way... Why do youw ant to combine these fields what is the perceived benefit?

Comment: I need it to be the primary key I stated above. This allows my file to work properly. There is nothing wrong with this primary key. Just tell me how to make. I am using mysql

Comment: @xQbert your example is not right. Please look at my proposed table and what your output produced

Comment: Ok, I was missing one row in data set, and had the month, name not ordered, but the count is being auto generated based on a row number occurance of the month name and is accurate. https://dbfiddle.uk/KFwk3Z2Y  window/analytical  functions allow one to partition the data in groups (in this case name and month) the row_number function resets to 1 each time it encounters a different name and month. however, if you have someone in 2023 jan, and someone in 2024 jan; both will show jan and will increment the count.  for example Michael feb could be 2021,2022,2023; it appears that doesn't matter...

Answer (score 0):

Updated to use mySQL syntax instead of SQL server.

Using a window/analytic function Row_number() this can be achieved.
The exact order of your result can not be achieved as there is no way to define the order presented.  Sorting by name or by month will not achieve the presented results.  So there's no method to achieve the exact same order without another field such as a date/time.

Since month and name are a [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/keywords-8-0.html); they it has been escaped using backtics.

The CTE is just to generate your sample data you need to substitue your table name for the CTE.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/KS2YsY9u)

```
With CTE AS (
  SELECT 'Jan' as `month`, 'Jack' as `name` union all
  SELECT 'Jan' as `month`, 'Scott' as `name` union all
  SELECT 'Jan' as `month`, 'Michael' as `name` union all
  SELECT 'Jan' as `month`, 'Jack' as `name` union all
  SELECT 'Feb' as `month`, 'Jack' as `name` union all
  SELECT 'Feb' as `month`, 'Michael' as `name` union all
  SELECT 'Feb' as `month`, 'Michael' as `name` union all
  SELECT 'Feb' as `month`, 'Michael' as `name`)

SELECT concat(`month`
             , `name`
             , Row_number() over (partition by `month`, `name` order by `month`, `name`))  PK
     , `month`
     , `name` 
     , Row_number() over (partition by `month`, `name` order by `month`, `name`) as count
  
FROM CTE  --substitute your tablename here.
order by `month`, `name`
```

Giving us:

```
+-------------+-------+---------+-------+
|     PK      | month |  name   | count |
+-------------+-------+---------+-------+
| FebJack1    | Feb   | Jack    |   1   |
| FebMichael1 | Feb   | Michael |   1   |
| FebMichael2 | Feb   | Michael |   2   |
| FebMichael3 | Feb   | Michael |   3   |
| JanJack1    | Jan   | Jack    |   1   |
| JanJack2    | Jan   | Jack    |   2   |
| JanMichael1 | Jan   | Michael |   1   |
| JanScott1   | Jan   | Scott   |   1   |
+-------------+-------+---------+-------+
```

Note:

- I'm lazy and didn't want to spell out primary key in the SQL.  Plus, I don't like spaces in my column headers.

Comment: The problem I have with the above is that the code has to call out each name. I am working with a much larger dataset with 10,000+ vendor names

Comment: I don't follow.  The CTE with the "names"  (Jack, michael, jack etc) is just to generate sample data set to show it works.  If you use the select concat(`month`... and below changing the table name in the "FROM" clause from "CTE" to your table name. and just run that select it should be fine.  The Demo link provides an example of this